# Is there a complete orthornomal basis of a Hilbert space which takes positive values on a discrete set?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Is there a complete orthonormal basis $\{f_n\}$ (of continuous functions) of the Hilbert space of square integrable functions on $[0,\,\infty)$ for which there exists a countable set $S\subset [0,\,\infty)$ such that $\forall x \in S$ we have $f_n(x)\geq 0,\, \forall n?$

Or could anyone point me to a paper on a similar topic?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The question is slightly ill-posed as elements of $L_2$ are not really functions but equivalence classes modulo the relation of being equal a.e. Therefore you can easily arrange this on some representatives. Perhaps you are interested in *continuous functions*?

Comment: Thank you for the observation Tomek, I indeed need them to be continuous. I have added the requirement. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since two functions are equal, up to a set of measure zero, one can always do this. Take any orthonormal basis and a discrete set. Assign a positive value to the basis functions at every point in the discrete set. We are through now. Am I making it correctly? Correct me if it is wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're right. See my comment above.

Comment: I should definitely have specified continuous. I'll add the change to the question. Thank you!